# How to cleanup/close questions that have been asked on other SE sites?

Tags: discussion

I looked through unanswered questions and found [this old one](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/62402/how-many-people-were-killed-by-protestant-inquisition-style-tribunals-asking-fo) which has a duplicate on History.SE, where it has some answers (none accepted). It also feels like History.SE is the better suited place. I think it makes sense closing it, to clean up. I think if someone still wants to answer the question, the History.SE version is the better place.

However none of the close reasons seem really fitting. Can I have some guidance here?

Answer (score 1):

If we think that a question would be better suited on another site, then we can migrate it, though migrations generally should only happen when it's either clearly off-topic here, or if it's borderline but would be much better suited somewhere else. There is an age limit however, we can't migrate questions older than three months.

The existence of duplicate questions on other sites isn't enough of a reason to close a question if it is on-topic here. So the question is whether it's actually off-topic. This particular question may be more on the pure historical side than the church history side, but I don't think it's off-topic. But if you think it is, then you can vote to close it.

Comment: In this case it's literally the same person asking the same question on two sites.

Comment: @kutschkem We discourage cross-posting, but cross-posting isn't actually a reason to close a question.

Comment: I see. I'm still confused as to whether that means I should just leave it alone. Are historical questions on-topic? Probably, right?

Comment: @kutschkem Just consider it on its own terms for this site. As I said, you can vote to close it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could vote to close, pick "Community-specific reason" then "Other" and then for the comment, you could link to the question on the other (better) SE site where it has an answer.